# Is it possible to animate background url using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, navigation, jquery-animate, hyperlink, fade

I am wondering if it is possible to animate background url using jQuery, and if not, what alternatives I have.  My nav bar HTML looks like this:

```
<li><a href="index.html" class="fade nav top current" id="index"><img style="margin: 90px 0 0 0px" src="images/home.png"></a></li>
     <li><a href="about.html" class="fade nav bottom" id="about"><img class="flip" style="margin: 84px 3px 0 0px" src="images/about.png"></a></li>
     <li><a href="#" id="contact" class="nav top"><img style="margin: 82px 2px 0 0px" src="images/contact.png"></a></li>
```

Then the CSS for the links in the nav bar looks like this:

```
a.nav {
    height: 170px;
    width: 118px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

a.top, a.bottom {
    background: url('images/bodhi-leaf-brown.png') no-repeat;
}

a.current, nav a:hover {
    background: url('images/bodhi-leaf-green.png') no-repeat !important;
}
```

Then I have a jQuery script which both controls the sliding of a contact form and adds and removes the class "current" to/from the nav links so that the background image changes:

```
$(function ()
{

    var newHash = "",
        $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
        $pageWrap = $("#page-wrap"),
        baseHeight = 0,
        $el,
    curTab = "#index";

    $("nav").delegate("a.fade", "click", function ()
    {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#panel").slideUp("slow");
        $(this).addClass("current", 3000);
        $("#contact").removeClass("current", 3000);
        return false;
    });

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function ()
    {

        newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

        if (newHash)
        {
            $pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
            baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();

            $mainContent
                .find("#guts")
                .fadeOut(500, function ()
                {
                    $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts", function ()
                    {
                        $pageWrap.animate({ height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px" }, function ()
                        {
                            $mainContent.fadeIn(500);
                            $pageWrap.css("height", "auto"); 
                        });

                        $("nav a").removeClass("current");
                    curTab = "#" + /^(.+)\..+$/.exec(newHash)[1];
                    $(curTab).addClass("current");
                    });
                });
        };
    });

$("#contact").click(function ()
{
    $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
    $(this).addClass("current");
    $("#index, #about").removeClass("current");
    return false;
});

$(".close").click(function ()
{
    $("#panel").slideUp("slow");
    $(curTab).addClass("current");
    $("#contact").removeClass("current");
    return false;
});

    $(window).trigger('hashchange');

});
```

I am wanting to have a fade between the background images on hover and for the click functions too.  Hence my question about animating the background images using jQuery.  If it is not possible to do this, is there another method that I could use which would incorporate the existing script that I have?

You can see the page as it currently stands [here](http://nickputman.com/test/).

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: just change the css 'background' property.

Comment: @bitsMix Thanks. Can you explain a bit more about what you mean.  Is it possible to animate the CSS background property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how you can use the hover function with animate. There are more effect just find the right for you on the jQuery document [page](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for animation.

```
 $("nav a").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: .6
        }, {
            duration: 100,
            specialEasing: {
                opacity: 'linear',
            },
            complete: function() {

                $(this).addClass("aHover").animate({
                    opacity: 1
                }, {
                    duration: 100,
                    specialEasing: {
                        opacity: 'linear',
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }, function() {
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: .6
        }, {
            duration: 100,
            specialEasing: {
                opacity: 'linear',
            },
            complete: function() {

                $(this).removeClass("aHover").animate({
                    opacity: 1
                }, {
                    duration: 100,
                    specialEasing: {
                        opacity: 'linear',
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

[hover animate](http://jsfiddle.net/x9xF9/)

Comment: Thanks.  That is looking promising!  Can you advise as to how I can make the fading effect longer though?  I would like a fairly quick fade on hover, i.e. 500ms and a longer fade out when the user 'leaves' the div, i.e. 3000ms.  I have tried adjusting the duration in your script, but because of the method you are using, it doesn't look right.

Comment: duration: 100 - change it to whatever you need. for the opacity also opacity: .6 (use values from 0 to 1)

Comment: Thanks.  I have tried that too.  It seems that using your method, one background needs to be faded out fully, before the other can be faded in, which is not what I am looking for.  I need a proper cross-fade, so that the leaves just change colour from brown to green and back.

Comment: OK, I have marked your answer as the correct one, as it does answer the question.  I am now trying a different method which uses divs with absolute positioning and jquery to animate the fading in of a div with the green leaves in, rather than background-images, as I think this will work better for my purposes.  I am incorporating some of your code in this.  Thanks, Nick